# Need help locating syntax error in large 16MB JSON file

Tags: php, json

I have a 16MB JSON file that PHP's json_last_error() tells me has a JSON Syntax Error.  Unfortunately I have no idea WHERE the syntax error is.  There are many online validators, but my data contains sensitive info that I'm not comfortable putting online.  Is there a JSON validator available that I can download?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Firebug extension in Firefox, or the built-in Chrome developer tools.

Get a bare local HTML page that you have the [javascript file](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) included with/in json2.js. Load up the file resource in your browser, and enable the debugging tools.

[JsonValidator](http://jsonvalidator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/%20jsonvalidator/jsonvalidator.js) works with Firebug console.

Comment: Thanks.  Just a note here: The Chrome validator had a difficult time swallowing the 16MB file.  It was a real slug, but my dev machine only has 4MB RAM.  I wonder how much better it would work on a beefier machine?

Comment: @user300266 I assume you mean you have 4GB ram; if you tried to load a 16MB file on 4MB ram... yeah, that will not go well (if at all).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint

This is the source code of the JSON validator that powers http://jsonlint.com/ - if you look up the top right of the page you will find a link to it.

Comment: This looked very promising to me, but unfortunately it didn't work.  I think the file size is still the issue.  When I ran it, it just sat there at the command prompt for a long time (I gave it 2 to 3 minutes).  During this time the CPU was pegged at 100%.  I stopped it and gave up.